# How to maintain single language folder for all plugins in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to maintain a single language folder for all plugins in ckeditor. Now each plugins has it own language folder. And my ckeditor version is 4.6. I want to release production how i do that?

Comment: Plz check the link https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/uilanguages.html

Comment: when I do like as you mentioned . what is the use of lang property is plugin.js? The ckeditor omits lang properties or what will happen?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a little more?

Comment: Check https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/uilanguage.html